# Use regex to find variables into string

Tags: php, mysql, regex, variables, replace

I'm not able to find out some regex to match multiple php variables into a string

*below is an example:*

```
$var = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE admin='".$admin."' AND id=".$idclient." AND something=".$something;
```

so actually I need to **match the whole query string and replace only variables** with a function() with variables inside.

The **final result** that I need should looks like:

```
$var = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE admin='".functionname($admin)."' AND id=".functionname($idclient)." AND something=".functionname($something);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Don't put these things in a string. Put them in an array, then rewrite the contents of the array using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood your requirements, then you can try like this with `regex`

```
<?php
$re = '/([$][a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*+)/m';
$str = '"SELECT * FROM table WHERE admin=\'".$admin."\' AND id=".$idclient." AND something=".$something;';
$subst = 'functionname($1)';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
?>
```

**REGEX:** https://regex101.com/r/1Jg5FN/3

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/DXuMr

Comment: PHP variable syntaxe is described [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). Also, if you want to edit PHP code with PHP itself (without falling in a pitfall), the best way is to use the [tokenizer](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thankx for the link, regex updated

Comment: Doing this with regular expressions is asking for trouble, *especially* if you have to call `eval` on that later. This code has the potential to become a huge liability.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem much more easily if you do this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE admin=? AND id=? AND something=?';

$values = array_map('functionname', [ $admin, $idclient, $something ]);
```

Then you can forward that array through to whatever execution method you're using.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I forgot to say that I don't need a script-based solution, because I'm going to use the "Find & Replace" functionality on several files and lines of code

Comment: That's going to be an even huger problem. You need to separate your data from your code in order to have any hope of success there. PHP's syntax, like many programming languages, is full of surprises.